# Using NSURLConnection async connection, how to get the received data in main function?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

some codes in httpController.h like this:

```
@interface httpController:NSObject{
  ...
  NSMutableData *receivedData;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
```

and some codes in httpController.m file like this:

```
@implementation httpController
@synthesize receivedData;
...
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
  [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data               
{
  if (!receivedData) {
      receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  }
  [receivedData appendData:data];  
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

}
```

Then I want using the receivedData in the main.m file, like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   HttpController *httpController = [[HttpController alloc] init];
   NSURLRequest *request = ...;
   NSURLConnection *connetion = ...;
   if(connection)
   {
     NSMutableData *_receviedData = httpController.receivedData;
     NSString * dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_receviedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]; 
     NSLog(@"%@",dataString);
   }
   [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
}
```

But i found that in the main() function, the value of _receivedData is empty, and there is noting outputted. Anyone can tell me What's wrong about it?

Comment: Your `httpDelegate` derives from `Object` and not `NSObject`?  It's not a delegate (in the Objective-C sense) and should probably start with a capital letter.

Comment: oh,I made a mistake and I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+connectionWithRequest:delegate:` runs asynchronously. It looks like it's not finishing the connection before returning, which is why you don't see any data. Try `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` instead, as this will block the thread until the connection finishes.

There's no need for a HttpController/delegate when using `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` either. Here's how to do it:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSURL           *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com/"];
    NSURLRequest    *request    = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse   *response   = nil;
    NSError         *error      = nil;

    // This blocks "this" thread until it's done.
    NSData          *data       = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (!data)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        NSLog(@"%@", dataString);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to block the thread, then `+connectionWithRequest:delegate:` is the way to go. But you'll have to write your code differently, and [should read the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dave. I want to develop a command line tool without GUI, and have to take the asynchronous communication mode. Could you give me any further advice?

Comment: I think your comment got cut off. Mind adding another so I can help you?

Comment: I want to download large data from server through http protocol, so i have to using the asynchronous mode. However, I have to do deal some other business in the main thread (that is the main() function) according to the received data. What I want to do is get the received data in the main() function with using asynchronous http connection mode.

Comment: Ah, in that case definitely read the docs I linked. Also, since main() will finish before the asynchronous non-blocking NSURLConnection is done, you'll have to create some other function/method for your HttpController to call when the NSURLConnection finishes.

Let HttpController create and track the connection. If it succeeds, have HttpController call that function/method, passing the returned data. If the connection fails, handle the error accordingly. One more note, `+connection:didReceiveResponse:` should release `receivedData` if it's non-nil as it may be called multiple times (see docs).

Comment: I see. but I do not know where to call the HttpController function/method. I try to place the calling before/after the sentence of "[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];", but both are invalid.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Mostly when I write Obj-C code I don't put anything in main(), but rather in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in an `AppDelegate.m` object. main() usually returns `return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);`, so I'm not sure how that handles runloops internally.